# draw curved arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can you make my two arrows more like the ones in the photo.

[image: arrow]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(4,1)--(4,7)--(0,6)--(-4,7)--(-4,1)--cycle;
\draw(0,0)--(0,6);
\node (a) at (.715, 6.5) {};
\node (b) at (-.715, 6.5) {};
\draw[->] (a)  to [out=120,in=60] (b);

\draw (9,7)--(13,7)--(12,3.5)--(13,0)--(9,0)--(8,3.5)--cycle;
\draw(12,3.5)--(8,3.5);
\draw(13,7)--(9.175,7.1)--(9.125,7.);
\draw(13,0)--(9.14,-.12)--(9.1,0);

\node (d) at (12.75, 3.8) {};
\node (c) at (12.5, 3.2) {};
\draw[->] (c)  to [out=90,in=90] (d);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about drawing a semi - circle and then adding `->` ?

Comment: If you have the two end points I'd just do a bezier curve using relative polar coordinates for the two control points

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Place the points (c) and (d) with the same separation used in (a) and (b). Use proper values for `in` and `out` keywords, and control the "roundness" of the curve with the `looseness` keyword:

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(4,1)--(4,7)--(0,6)--(-4,7)--(-4,1)--cycle;
\draw(0,0)--(0,6);
\node (a) at (.715, 6.5) {};
\node (b) at (-.715, 6.5) {};
\draw[->] (a)  to [out=90,in=90, looseness=2] (b);


\draw (9,7)--(13,7)--(12,3.5)--(13,0)--(9,0)--(8,3.5)--cycle;
\draw(12,3.5)--(8,3.5);
\draw(13,7)--(9.175,7.1)--(9.125,7.);
\draw(13,0)--(9.14,-.12)--(9.1,0);

\node (d) at (12.5, 3.5 + .715) {};
\node (c) at (12.5, 3.5 - .715) {};
\draw[->] (c)  to [out=0,in=0,looseness=2] (d);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]